# Does ExtJS4 MVC supports to define stores under a sub folder of "store"

Tags: javascript, extjs4

Under "Getting References" on http://www.sencha.com/learn/architecting-your-app-in-ext-js-4-part-3, sencha gives an example to refer to the store instance by the automatically generated getter:

```
stores: ['Stations']    
// creates getter named 'getStationsStore', returns the Stations store instance
```

In this example, the "Stations" is placed directly under the "store" folder.

But in my case, I'd like to put the store classes under the sub folders of "store" in order to make the structure more clear. The definition of one store would be "APPNAME.store.aspect1.MyStore". I have three questions:

1. Is such definition allowed under ExtJS4 MVC?
2. If it's allowed, then what's the automatically generated getter for it, or how can I refer to it in a controller?
3. Where could I find a good open source example using ExtJS4? (the examples provided by sencha are too simple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it is. I use it to package stores together all the time.
2. I don't have an example handy, but I believe it should be get + PackageName + StoreName + Store(). So in the example you shared, I think it would be getAspect1MyStoreStore()
3. Do you have particular examples in mind? There are a lot of ExtJS4 examples out there. Do you want MVC examples, Store examples, Component examples, etc?

Comment: 1 & 2: It works! I found I need to use
    "stores: ['aspect1.MyStore']"
rather than
    "stores: ['APPNAME.store.aspect1.MyStore']"
in the beginning of the controller. What's the difference between them?

3: I want MVC examples - especially working with Java Servlet.

Comment: Yes, by convention the stores config in controllers will always start at the default store location.

Comment: RE: the MVC examples, I'll get back with you in a bit. Good luck!

Comment: Dear existdissolve, any updates about the MVC examples? Thanks!